# Web scraping with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

let say i have an html document

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div>
        <p --data-some-att = "My Value">Paragraph with Data> </p>

        <a href="someuri" --data-some-link= "true">LINK<a/>

        <a href="someuri" >LINK With No data attr<a/>

        <p>My Paragrah with out data </p>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

i want to find all the elements which have data attributes like the one above(`--data-some-att`). so far i can only find all the locations where these attributes are found and here is the code

```
    var vRegex = /\-\-data\-some\-attr\=\"/gi;

    var vResult,vIndices = [];
    while ( ( vResult = vRegex.exec(htmldocument) ) ) 
    {
        vIndices.push(vResult.index);
    }
```

so now i have an array of all the occurrences but how can i get the whole element like the `<p>` or `<a>` only the one that have a data attribute like (--data-some-att). i am using nodejs and i will highly appreciate any help on getting all other attributes of the element which has a specific attribute set.

thank you!

Comment: Don't parse html with regex. Use something like https://cheeriojs.github.io/cheerio/ or another html parser.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: `--data-some-link=<...>` is not  valid syntax for an attribute AFAIK.